# Notice: Undefined variable: twig

Tags: php, twig

i dont kown twig how use in composer Controllers.

1 composer.json :

```
"require": {
        "php": ">=7.2.0",
        "filp/whoops": "*",
        "noahbuscher/macaw": "dev-master",
        "twig/twig": "^2.0"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "App/"
        },
        "files":[]
    }
```

2 Controllers :

Controllers
  |-HomeController.php
  |-ShareControllers.php

3 ShareControllers.php :

```php
<?php


namespace  App\Controllers;


class ShareControllers
{
    public function __construct()
    {

        $loader = new \Twig\Loader\FilesystemLoader(VIEW_PATH);
        $twig = new \Twig\Environment($loader, [
            'cache' => CACHE_PATH,
            'debug' => true
        ]);

    }
}
```

4 HomeController.php :

```php
namespace  App\Controllers;


class HomeController extends ShareControllers
{
    public function index(){
        echo $twig->render('content.html', ['name' => 'hi']);
    }

}
```

so:

```
Notice: Undefined variable: twig  :(
```

Comment: In `__construct()` you are setting local variable `$twig` which is not accessible out of its scope. So no surprise it is "undefined" in other method

Comment: Basically, you probably meant to use `$this->twig` in both lines (and you should probably add the property to the ShareControllers class explicitly).

Comment: If the answer below solved your issue, you should accept it. If it doesn't, please comment under the answer and explain what happens.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a scoping issue. You're currently just storing the twig instance in a local variable that's only accessible within that methods scope. You need to add it as a class property:

```
class ShareControllers
{
    protected $twig;

    public function __construct()
    {    
        $loader = new \Twig\Loader\FilesystemLoader(VIEW_PATH);

        // Adding $this-> will store it in the above defined property
        $this->twig = new \Twig\Environment($loader, [
            'cache' => CACHE_PATH,
            'debug' => true
        ]);
    }
}
```

Now, in your child class, you can access it using:

```
class HomeController extends ShareControllers
{
    public function index(){
        // Here we also use $this-> to fetch the instance
        echo $this->twig->render('content.html', ['name' => 'hi']);
    }

}
```

I would recommend reading the manual about [class properties](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.properties.php) and [variable scopes](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php).